# Bash: getting values from file

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a file that is built like this:

```
(MATH[NUMBER1=(50, unknown, unknown), NUMBER2=(unknown, 4, unknown), OPERATOR='times']
 (NUM[SEM=(50, unknown, unknown)] (DIZAINE[SEM=50] cinquante))
  (OPERATEUR[SEM='times'] multiplie)
  (NUM[SEM=(unknown, 4, unknown)] (UNITE[SEM=4] quatre)))
```

How can I extract the values 50, 'times' & 4?

I've tried with awk but there are parentheses balancing issues

Comment: IMHO it would be better to try to identify the file format and locate a parser that is designed to handle it - treating input like this as unstructured text is almost certain to result in a fragile error prone solution. In any case, *which* `times` and *which* `4` do you wish to extract?

Comment: I'm not sure if one exists (this is the output of a program hashed together by one of my professors). I don't mind which values get selected, but ideally not the ones on the first line

Comment: So... you want to extract non-parenthesized values of the `SEM` attribute?

Comment: yes... I'm guessing bash won't make that easy?

Comment: `bash` won't make it any easier, but  more advanced scripting languages - such as python or perl - they could do the job.

Comment: I'm thinking of going down the Python route, any tips? I'm a bit rusty

Comment: Might require `re` for regular expressions module. I'll try to come up with something and will post  if I do

Comment: Btw, this looks a lot like `clojure` language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to extract the *non parenthesized values of the `SEM` attribute* then you can do so using `grep` in PCRE mode:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=\[SEM=)[^()]*?(?=\])' file
50
'times'
4
```

or `perl` itself

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /(?<=\[SEM=)([^()]*?)(?=\])/' file
50
'times'
4
```

Both approaches use regular expression [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 4):

With a few `re` module commands, we can put together a Python script as so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys,re
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        items = re.findall(r'SEM=[^(]+?\]',line)
        for i in items:
            tokens = filter( lambda x: x != 'SEM' and x, re.split('=|]',i)  )
            print("\n".join(tokens))
```

With your given input that produces:

```
$ ./get_sem_vals.py ./input.txt
50
'times'
4
```

I also took liberty to account for possible multiple `SEM` values on same line. If we modify your second line as

```
 (NUM[SEM=(50, unknown, unknown)] (DIZAINE[SEM=50] cinquante, ATHING=[SEM=25]))
```

the script produces the following output:

```
$ ./get_sem_vals.py ./input.txt
50
25
'times'
4
```